# Select next Item in Listview on Repeatbutton Click

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a Listview and I need a special behavior.
When I click the increase/decrease-Button in that ListView, I want to select the next/previous item in it. I have no clue how to do that.
I can't find a click handler for the repeatbuttons to increase/decrease the selectedItem-Field.
What I tried is to name them in the template and try to get them by FindName(). But no result on that.

So, if anyone has an idea, please offer it here.

Thanks in advance,
Readonly

Comment: RepeatButton has a Click event. show some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this logic to help you. try it on your own and show some code

```
        ListBox1.SelectedIndex += 1; // increase

        ListBox1.SelectedIndex -= 1;  //decrease
```

Comment: I still don't know how to get the Instance of the RepeatButtons inside the Scrollviewer of the ListBox. Now I used Blend to get the Clickhandler. Works fine for me. Thank you guys for your participation!